# Vagrant destroyed on host shut down, Windows

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant

After working in a Vagrant VM and making some changes I will suspend the VM using vagrant suspend. If I then restart the host computer and then attempt to run vagrant resume, the terminal sits for a bit and then brings me back to a command prompt without any feedback. So, naturally I then try vagrant ssh, and I receive the following:

> VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up` to start the virtual machine.

If I run vagrant up, I find that all the changes I made prior to the suspend have been overwriten by the base box import.

Is this intended behavior? I am runny Windows 8 pro x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me every now and then, I reboot and there's no trace of my vagrant machine anymore. Even running `vboxmanage list vms` doesn't show my VM, but if I reboot my computer again and this time I open Virtualbox GUI before trying to do `vboxmanage list vms` (or don't open it first depending on which way failed on previous attempt) and it'll list my Vagrant machine and its ID.

Armed with this ID I can go into .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/ and create a file named "id" and add a single line containing the id of the vagrant machine. And after that you can start it with `vagrant up` it's probably safest to add --no-provision though as it has happened that it's started provisioning even though a machine already existed..

Comment: I can confirm this, reproduceable, on multiple Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machines in my company. It's a bug in the showdown-process of Virtualbox as it seems (the machine is not shut down properly).

Comment: I confirm that adding a unique file called "id" and containing the name of the VM works. You can resume your VM lilke this and retrieve data. But I add the following issue now :
==> default: Resuming suspended VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot.
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...

Comment: What is the correct procedure after starting vagrant up. If you reboot/restart your host do you need to shut it down or call vagrant halt?

Answer (score 6):

The idea of vagrant is to use the base box and then make customizations with provisioning methods. So always a `vagrant destroy` (removes all data of the VM) and `vagrant up` builts the box again, based on the base box, should work.

Anyways, you did not do a `vagrant destroy` the data should still be there.

If you did a `vagrant suspend` that means the boxes state is frozen by Virtual Box.

Next, you should do a `vagrant resume`: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/resume.html

But if you did a `vagrant up` in between, the data might be lost. You could open the VirtualBox GUI and see if there are still some preserved snapshots.

Comment: I played around with it some more. If I remain vigilant about suspending before a shut down of the host I seem to be ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have windows, it did some windows updates while vagrant was running overnight and restarted my entire computer. I didnt get a chance to halt/suspend vagrant, I go back to vagrant bin directory, and run vagrant up, or vagrant resume in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest creating a project directory for each VM you plan to use. If you change into that empty project directory before doing `vagrant init` a dedicated `Vagrantfile` is created for that project/VM, which then can be customized to your needs. To use that customized `Vagrantfile` then, just run `vagrant up` from inside your projects directory. Not sure if this solves your problem but it's worth a try I guess. ;-)

Btw. you can check if your VM is running with the command `vagrant status [machine-name]`.

Comment: So, the workflow you are describing with the project directory is exactly what I am doing right now. I have a VagrantFile that can be used or modified. The problem though is if I use vagrant suspend, restart my machine, go back to that directory and call vagrant resume, I cannot get the VM to resume. It tells me that the VM needs to be created first. Then when I do the vagrant up command, the VM is rebuilt, but it is missing any DBs that I may have created,

Comment: @spetz83 if I understand vagrant correctly, the DB (e.g. MySQL) runs on the VM, but the actual data should live in a shared directory on the host computer. That goes for any data that needs to persist.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently encountered a somewhat similar situation, and ultimately discovered that there is a scenario where a 'vagrant suspend' effectively destroys a VM.  That's running Vagrant on a Windows host with Virtual Box 4.3.14 as the virtualization provider.  Rolling Virtual Box back to 4.3.12 is a way to work around the issue.  Details here:  https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4276

Comment: Yes, VirtualBox 4.3.14/4.3.16 seems to be badly broken on Windows hosts. I had the same issue of `vagrant halt` followed by `vagrant up` would attempt to recreate the vm. That would fail because it couldn't overwrite the existing one and I had to manually clean up everything and start again. Please contribute here to help fix this issue https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=63556

Comment: Btw this also happens on Linux.